# How to change (upgrade or downgrade) Angular version in WebStorm?

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular13

WebStorm was installed by me today. I  need to compile an Angular project.

Their current Angular version is 15.0.5. I would like to use Angular CLI: 13.0.4. How can I change my Angular version from whatever version I have to whichever one I choose?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://update.angular.io/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Npx with angular cli, how to install @angular/cli and use it afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54184357/npx-with-angular-cli-how-to-install-angular-cli-and-use-it-afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

you first need to install the desired angular version **globaly** by using "**-g**"

then you will have the option to choose your version , in your case :

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@13.0.4
```

here is the result :
[image]
for me i needed the 13.3.3 version but you can install your desired version